# What does comma mean as a length of array in C#

Tags: c#

The question is in title.

What does comma mean as a length of array in C#?

How it is called, how to find it on the Internet?

I searched for "how to initialize array in C#" in google but there is no information about this comma.
If I remove comma VS shows an error: "array initializers can only be used in a variable".
Even after assigning it to variable it still shows error.

EntityFramework generates the following code:

```cs
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "Test",
            columns: new[] { "Name" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
                { "Test" },
                { "Test1" }
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: Without initializer, you can do `var my2DArray = new object[3,2];` - the comma separates the dimensions

Comment: Thank you guys. It helped. I didn't event guess it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coma does not represent a length, it represent a dimension. In your case, it can be called a [2d array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/array-dimensions). It allows you to do this:

```
values: new object[,]
{
    { "Testa", "Testb", "Testc" },
    { "Test1a", "Test1b", "Test1c" }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even know about this feature.

Comment: FYI It is not an array of arrays.  That would be a jagged array as in `object[][]`.